# how to move images from one table to another table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to build a website which shows one image at a time in frontend from the database and move the displayed image from the existing table to another table. my website is in Django

Comment: Are images stored in your database somehow or is it image files located somewhere in a media folder? If one moves an image from one table to another, would that action be: make new record in another table, delete from existing table? Why does it have to be in one or the other?

Comment: I guess you have to write a signal for that.